# wine emulated program crashes while saving

Tags: wine, 32-bit

Wine ran program crashes while saving.

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000074 in 32-bit code (0x00692199).
```

and

```
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (126 modules)
PE    400000-  bf7000   Export          cmsuite9
ELF 7b400000-7b7ea000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b410000-7b7ea000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcfa000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcfa000   \               ntdll
ELF 7c000000-7c004000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7c4ba000-7c500000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  7c4c0000-7c500000   \               usp10
PE  7c6a6000-7c6bb000   Deferred        api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1
PE  7c6b0000-7c6bb000   Deferred        api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1C:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-1.dll
ELF 7c72b000-7c753000   Deferred        propsys<elf>
  \-PE  7c730000-7c753000   \               propsys
ELF 7c753000-7c813000   Deferred        windowscodecs<elf>
  \-PE  7c760000-7c813000   \               windowscodecs
ELF 7c813000-7c827000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1<e
PE  7c820000-7c827000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1
PE  7c8b1000-7c8c5000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-
PE  7c8c0000-7c8c5000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-C:\windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-1.dll
ELF 7c8c5000-7c8d9000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1<el
PE  7c8d0000-7c8d9000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-fibers-l1-1-1
ELF 7c8d9000-7c8ef000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7c8ef000-7c964000   Deferred        libpcre.so.3
ELF 7c964000-7c981000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7c981000-7ca30000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.20
ELF 7ca30000-7ca56000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF 7ca56000-7ca5f000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7ca5f000-7ca85000   Deferred        libselinux.so.1
ELF 7ca85000-7cb14000   Deferred        libsystemd.so.0
ELF 7cb14000-7cb1d000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF 7cb1d000-7cb36000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7cb36000-7cb3b000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7cb3b000-7cb95000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7cb95000-7cc21000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
ELF 7cc21000-7cc56000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.4
ELF 7cc56000-7cc93000   Deferred        libnettle.so.6
ELF 7cc93000-7cca8000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF 7cca8000-7ccdc000   Deferred        libidn.so.11
ELF 7ccdc000-7cd3d000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7cd3d000-7cd6e000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 7cd6e000-7ce44000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 7ce44000-7ce58000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 7ce58000-7cfb0000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF 7cfb0000-7d002000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 7d002000-7d089000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 7d097000-7d0ab000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0<elf
PE  7d0a0000-7d0ab000   Deferred        api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0
ELF 7d0ab000-7d0b2000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7d0b2000-7d0be000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7d0be000-7d0d1000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7d0d1000-7d0d5000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7d0d5000-7d0e2000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7d0e2000-7d0ee000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7d0ee000-7d0f5000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7d0f5000-7d0f9000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7d0f9000-7d100000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7d100000-7d104000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7d104000-7d12a000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7d12a000-7d275000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7d275000-7d28a000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7d28a000-7d297000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 7d297000-7d29c000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF 7d29c000-7d2aa000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 7d2ac000-7d33a000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7d2c0000-7d33a000   \               winex11
ELF 7d4f5000-7d51f000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7d51f000-7d568000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7d568000-7d593000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7d593000-7d643000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7d665000-7d734000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE  7d670000-7d734000   \               crypt32
ELF 7d734000-7d75f000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7d740000-7d75f000   \               msacm32
ELF 7d75f000-7d817000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7d770000-7d817000   \               winmm
ELF 7d817000-7d83b000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7d820000-7d83b000   \               imm32
ELF 7d83b000-7d899000   Deferred        oleacc<elf>
  \-PE  7d840000-7d899000   \               oleacc
ELF 7d899000-7d8c1000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7d8a0000-7d8c1000   \               mpr
ELF 7d8c1000-7d8fb000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7d8d0000-7d8fb000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7d91e000-7d939000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7d939000-7d9cc000   Deferred        gdiplus<elf>
  \-PE  7d950000-7d9cc000   \               gdiplus
ELF 7d9cc000-7da07000   Deferred        oledlg<elf>
  \-PE  7d9d0000-7da07000   \               oledlg
ELF 7da07000-7db39000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7da20000-7db39000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7db39000-7dbba000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7db40000-7dbba000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7dbba000-7dd15000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7dbd0000-7dd15000   \               ole32
ELF 7dd15000-7dd4d000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7dd20000-7dd4d000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7dd4d000-7dd8d000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  7dd50000-7dd8d000   \               winspool
ELF 7dd8d000-7deac000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7dd90000-7deac000   \               comctl32
ELF 7deac000-7df22000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7dec0000-7df22000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7df22000-7e796000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7df30000-7e796000   \               shell32
ELF 7e796000-7e881000   Dwarf           comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE  7e7a0000-7e881000   \               comdlg32
ELF 7e881000-7e895000   Deferred        msimg32<elf>
  \-PE  7e890000-7e895000   \               msimg32
ELF 7e895000-7e90d000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e8a0000-7e90d000   \               advapi32
ELF 7e90d000-7ea3c000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e920000-7ea3c000   \               gdi32
ELF 7ea3c000-7ec1c000   Dwarf           user32<elf>
  \-PE  7ea50000-7ec1c000   \               user32
ELF 7ec1c000-7ec2f000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ec2f000-7ec3c000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ec3c000-7ec57000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ef89000-7efde000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe6000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF f73d9000-f73de000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f73de000-f7594000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f7594000-f75b1000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f75b6000-f75c0000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f75d3000-f778a000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f778b000-f77b0000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f77b2000-f77b3000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    00000025    0
    00000022    0
    0000001d    0
    00000013    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000011 winedevice.exe
    0000001a    0
    00000017    0
    00000016    0
    00000012    0
0000001b plugplay.exe
    0000001f    0
    0000001e    0
    0000001c    0
00000020 winedevice.exe
    0000002a    0
    00000024    0
    00000023    0
    00000021    0
00000028 explorer.exe
    0000002d    0
    0000002c    0
    0000002b    0
    00000029    0
0000002e (D) C:\Program Files (x86)\SciEd9\CMSuite9.exe
    00000031    0
    0000002f    0 <==
System information:
    Wine build: wine-3.0.4
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows XP
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.4.0-170-generic
```

What should I do to make it save files without crashing?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the name says it: Wine Is Not an Emulator.

The program is trying to access memory location `0x74` and getting an "Out of Bounds" error. This is probably due to a programming error, or IDK, some magic Windows location in 32-bit mode. Not a `wine` problem.

`wine` doesn't support ALL Windows programs.

Report this error to the Windows program provider.